# Running PHP script does not work

Tags: php, magento

I have a php script for my magento page which fixes texterrors. It worked fine when I had like 10 products in my shop. Now I do have over 3000 and if I try to run the script, it takes about 3 seconds and then an empty page is shown.

```
<?php
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$yourstring = array( 'Ã¤', 'Ã¶' , 'Ã' , 'Ã¼' , 'Â°' , '<short_description>' , '</short_description>    <full_description>' , '</full_description>' , '</weight>');
$newstring =  array( 'ä' , 'ö'  , 'ø'    , 'ü'  , '°'  , 'SHORT_DESCRIPTION'   , 'SHORT_DESCRIPTION'                          , 'DELETE'              , 'DELETE');

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();

echo 'RUNNING SCRIPT...<br /><br /><br /><br />';               
for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
  echo 'Letter to fix: '.$newstring[$i].'<br />';
  foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {

    if (strpos($_product->getDescription(),$yourstring[$i]) !== false) {

      $newdescription = str_replace($yourstring[$i],$newstring[$i],$_product->getDescription());
      $_product->setDescription($newdescription);
      $_product->save();

      echo 'Updated product: '.$_product->getName().'<br />';
    }

  }
  echo '<br /><br />';
}
?>
```

It should at least display the "RUNNING SCRIPT" message but it doesn't.
I'm really confused.

Thank you!

Comment: What is script timeout set to?

Comment: where can i find that out?

Comment: did you check the error logs? or turn on error reporting / display errors.  The white page of death.

Comment: the blank page suggests that you have an error somewhere. as suggested by @ArtisiticPhoenix, you should turn on error reporting, and/or check the error logs.

Comment: where can i turn that on? I'm just confused because the script worked fine and i did not change anything

Comment: It's more like memory overflow issue. $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load(); shows that you get ALL products with all their attributes, while you need to change only one attribute. This is not a good practice. Better is to use smaller chunks to work with...

Comment: ok, thank you. so how would i do this? how can i select like 100 products at once and do it step by step?

Comment: What is your loop `for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {` for..?   str_replace() takes 2 arrays as arguments and replaces element-for-element

Comment: it is for the single letterst that need to be fixed (the arrays shown above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the script (right before include) add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`. Thanks to that errors will be visible at the screen and you will be able to correct them.

If there is no errors and script will still behave as you described try change allowed execution time. For more information look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: thank you, but the script didn't show any errors and adding a longer execution time with the function set_time_limit did not help :(

Comment: Add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`, `ini_set("track_errors", 1);` and `ini_set("html_errors", 1);` before `error_reporting()` function and check if errors will apear.

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/customers/webs/Ihnken/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291

Comment: Well it's (just like @bksi said) memory overflow problem. You should select only attributes you want to modify and try to do it in smaller chunks. If I'm right that you use Zend Framework I'm sure that this information can be found somewhere in it's documentation.